# UnobservedComponents: How to Set Boundaries on Parameters Updates?

Tags: python, statsmodels

When fitting an `UnobservedComponents` model, is it possible to set upper boundaries for final values of the states parameters?

We'd like to simulate a Bayesian approach for choosing prior distribution over the states and setting final value to have upper boundary up to 20% of initial value (such that if we choose as prior for a local level the value 0.1 then final value would be at most 0.12).

The motivation behind comes from an algorithm we're porting from R to Python. When we fit a local level model on a given test data, final state sigma ends up being around 0.3; in R, there's the upper boundary assumption so final result is 0.12 which yields considerable different confidence intervals. We've been trying to model the same behavior in statsmodels now.

By studying the code we found the method [`transform_params`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/structural.py#L954) which seems to be able to introduce boundaries on initial state but we're not sure how to use it to set the 20% upper boundary (or whether it'd be the right approach).

Answer (score 0):

Just found a very simple and precise solution of what I was looking for: we can use the input parameter `bounds` and it will already limit the boundaries where the fitting algorithm will search for the optima value.

Here's an example in case someone needs to do the same:

```
model = UnobservedComponents(data, level='choose level', exog=more data)
bounds = [(None, None) for _ in range(len(model.param_names))]
```

If one wants to set the lower boundary of 0.1 and upper boundary of 0.12 for the level optimization and it corresponds to the index 1 in `model.param_names`, this can be done like so:

```
bounds[1] = (0.1, 0.12)
```

Then just run the `fit` command:

```
model.fit(bounds=bounds)
```

Keep in mind that those values in `bounds` corresponds to the **standard deviation** of the parameters, not its variance.

It worked like a charm :)